# How to find text in list, if they have a similar path

Tags: c#, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I recently started to learn selenium, c#

Please, help me to resolve my problem.

In my project, items are added to the cart.
And I need to check that they're added.For this purpose I am trying to find the text use XPath, CssSelector or ClassName. But in result I have one Error, Driver finds first element, compares and show error: the text does not match

How to get him to look further down the tree ?

Or some shorter way? If imagine 30 items in the cart,this process will take a long time....

Example, when I use Xpath:

```
Assert.AreEqual("text to search",
            driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='cartList2']/div[3]/div/div/span")).Text);
```

But, all items have the similar path, each item can be div[1]-2-3-4-5....(Depending on the order in which it was added)

Example of my page:

```
<div id="cartList2" class="k-listview k-widget">
    <div data-uid="c45003ff-536a-4293-b494-c6dde56c2d02" class="card-view k-widget ng-scope">
        <div class="row col-sm-12">
                <span bs-tooltip="" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-title="TEXT" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 description ng-scope ng-binding">TEXT</span>
            </div>
    </div>

    <div data-uid="91177f92-d790-47eb-8121-22eebe9e2610" class="card-view k-widget ng-scope">
        <div class="row col-sm-12">
                <span bs-tooltip="" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-placement="top" data-title="TEXT" class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 description ng-scope ng-binding">TEXT</span>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: why can't you use findElements?

Comment: What exactly you want not gettable

Comment: `items which are added to the cart` can't have the same `Text` as **TEXT** and **TEXT**. Update the question with relevant _HTML_.

Answer (score 0):

use can use dynamic xpath such as in your case: //div[@id='cartList2']/div[3]/div/div/span, you can edit div index as you need